# Null value not allowed while updating Database schema

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

i have an entity called "FosUser" :

```
<?php

namespace techeventBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * FosUser
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="UNIQ_957A6479A0D96FBF", columns={"email_canonical"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="UNIQ_957A647992FC23A8", columns={"username_canonical"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="UNIQ_957A6479C05FB297", columns={"confirmation_token"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_957A647914013572", columns={"copon_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class FosUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=180, nullable=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username_canonical", type="string", length=180, nullable=true)
     */
    private $usernameCanonical;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=180, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email_canonical", type="string", length=180, nullable=true)
     */
    private $emailCanonical;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $enabled;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_login", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastLogin;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="confirmation_token", type="string", length=180, nullable=true)
     */
    private $confirmationToken;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password_requested_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $passwordRequestedAt;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $roles;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
         */
        private $nom;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
         */
        private $prenom;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="tel", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
         */
        private $tel;

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="age", type="integer", nullable=false)
         */
        private $age;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="sexe", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $sexe;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="fonction", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $fonction;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $address;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="categorie", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $categorie;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $type;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $description;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $role;

        /**
         * @var \Coupon
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Coupon")
         * @ORM\JoinColumns({
         *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="copon_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         * })
         */
        private $copon;


    }
```

i have deleted  fields in this entity and changed the default value of fields to null ('nullable = true') like this  :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * FosUser
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="UNIQ_957A6479A0D96FBF", columns={"email_canonical"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="UNIQ_957A647992FC23A8", columns={"username_canonical"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="UNIQ_957A6479C05FB297", columns={"confirmation_token"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_957A647914013572", columns={"copon_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class FosUser extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $nom;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $prenom;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tel", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $tel;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="age", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $age;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sexe", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $sexe;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fonction", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $fonction;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $address;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="categorie", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $categorie;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $role;

    /**
     * @var \Coupon
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Coupon")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="copon_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    protected $copon;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

i had those errors after updating the database schema :

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:
>
> An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE fos_user CHANGE
>   username    username VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, CHANGE username_canonical
>   username_canonic   al VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, CHANGE email_canonical
>   email_canonical VARCHAR(18   0) NOT NULL, CHANGE enabled enabled
>   TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, CHANGE roles roles    LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT
>   '(DC2Type:array)', CHANGE nom nom VARCHAR(255) D   EFAULT NULL, CHANGE
>   prenom prenom VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL':
>
> SQLSTATE[22004]: Null value not allowed: 1138 Utilisation incorrecte
>   de la   valeur NULL
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 106:
>
> SQLSTATE[22004]: Null value not allowed: 1138 Utilisation incorrecte
>   de la   valeur NULL
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 104:
>
> SQLSTATE[22004]: Null value not allowed: 1138 Utilisation incorrecte
>   de la   valeur NULL

Comment: `and changed the default value of fields to null like this`  Maybe they were not null for a reason? `Null value not allowed:` - thats because the DB schema is set to NOT NULL for the row. So either change the DB so that it will accept null values, or put something other then null back in the ones that are not null.  Or insure that when you create a new record from a given entity that those required fields are populated.

Comment: is the error only about null values  ?

Comment: It looks like there are few rows with NULL value.Update all null values to a default value, then try to do an update.

Comment: @KubiRoazhon still getting the same error

Comment: Have you already some rows in your table ?

Comment: yes  i already have some rows there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right!
Previously you haven't used FOUser class, your fos_user table have already username, emailCanonical, etc ...
Then when you extend FOSUser and update database schema, your current entity doesn't accept null value for username, etc .. (It's FOSUser logic)

Solution, you have to delete your fos_user table before updating the database schema

Comment: there is no solution without deleting the table ? should i delete only the table or the whole 'FosUser' entity ? thanks for your answer .

Comment: I think that you should drop your "fos_user" table

Comment: Or run this SQL Command: 'UPDATE fos_user SET username = "oldUserData", ....'
Just to add some value into the null fields